# Eclipse the declared package does not match

Tags: java, package

I have an error on the package route, but this only happen on the main class, the others classes are fine, i tried everything but i dont know what is wrong here, and when i used the quickfix, this happened.

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Did you try Project >> Clean & ReBuild option ?

Answer (score 0):

You have set wrong "source folder". 
Now the "src" is a "package" but not a "source folder"

Please add "src" as "source folder" in project properties.